# Is C# approching functional programing?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Many new features of C# remind me of functional programs such as LINQ. As this makes many operations easier it clutters the language. Is this approach for good or bad?

Comment: Not really the right place to post discussions.

Comment: Where should it be posted then?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: LINQ is not a feature of C#, it's a feature of .NET.

Comment: Still it is a functional approach.

Comment: @jamietre: LINQ is not only a feature of C#, it is also a feature of VB.NET; but to make use of LINQ in a manner that makes sense, the language has to support it. For example, try to use LINQ in C++/CLI.

Comment: "LINQ is not only a feature of C#" was not the point of the question.

Comment: You could try discussing this on the new [C# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c).

Comment: C# is a multi-paradigm language which includes functional.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this approach for good or bad?

Good.